Does it matter which vocation I am using when I level up?
I have noticed as I have been levelling up the different vocations that the stats on level up seem to be different for each vocation.
Level up as Warrior

Level up as Mage

Are these stats a permanent change to my character? Does it matter what vocation I am using when I level up? Will changing vocation change my stats?
